# Installing Wordpress in Windows Hosting Godaddy Subfolder: 500 Server Error

Tags: wordpress

I have a newly purchased Windows Hosting in GoDaddy with its own domain name. Before anything else, I wanted to install a wordpress blog in the subfolder of the domain like so: `http://example.com/blog`. I followed the step by step tutorial provided by GoDaddy but when I try to browse example.com/blog it throws 500 server error.

I tried doing the same installation procedure but this time using the subdomain like so: `blog.example.com` and it worked without problem. I would like to use a subfolder in my domain instead of a subdomain. Is there a pre-configuration steps (nowhere to be found in the installation guide) I have to do in order to do so?

**UPDATE**: I tried browsing for solutions and it seemed to me that my problem might be about `.htaccess` but I don't exactly know how to configure or where to find it (im a total newbie in web hosting esp godaddy). Please ask if you need more details. Thank you.

Comment: solution: https://in.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/500-Internal-Error-message/td-p/4993

Comment: Solution: https://davidwalsh.name/mod_rewrite-htaccess-godaddy